# Occam razor, Schrödinger and Heisenberg pictures

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am curious about why Occam razor has failed to get rid of either the Schrödinger or the Heisenberg picture in quantum mechanics.

Both are equivalent descriptions of "nature", I do not know whether one could be argued to be simpler than the other. Even if not, why haven't we settled on a single description, in line with applying Occam razor?

Comment: Perhaps when Sweeney Todd completes his impersonation of Occam it would come to pass... Lorentz invariance is manifest in the Heisenberg picture, since the state vectors do not single out the time or space. But matrix mechanics, its home,  is disfavored, as people may be intimidated by algebraic methods. The actual interaction picture that QFT runs on is a co-equal *blend* of the Schr and H pictures, so you need both ingredients. Hell, even QM has 3 equivalent formulations, at the very least.....

Comment: How could Occam's razor apply here?  Moving from one picture to the other is essentially just a change of basis, isn't it?  From the Wikipedia article [Heisenberg picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture):  *The two pictures only differ by a basis change with respect to time-dependency, which corresponds to the difference between active and passive transformations.*

Comment: @AlfredCentauri feel free to write up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

They are just formalisms that help us to perform calculations. And Occam's razor does help us choose between these two pictures; we should use the one that is the simplest, for whatever specific application we have in mind.

Why would you expect a different answer?

Comment: For one, you answer is in clear contradiction with the top voted comment below my question.

Comment: @JohnDuffield'sdog In what way? We choose which basis is more convenient for the specific application. This is congruent with the spirit of the comment you refer to.

Comment: You're claiming that we apply Occam's razor to choose a basis while the top voted comment claims Occam's razor cannot be applied. Conflict.